# Get the most frequent number and least frequent duplicate in array

Tags: java, performance, array, statistics

This code gets the most frequent number and least duplicate number in an array.  How can I optimize it and improve its performance?

```
public class X {

public static String findMin(String[] numbers, int counter) {
int count = 0;
String elements = "";
for (String tempElement: numbers) {
  int tempCount = 0;
  for (int n = 0; n < numbers.length; n++) {
    if (numbers[n].equals(tempElement)) {
      tempCount++;
      if (tempCount > counter) {
        count = 0;
        break;
      }
      if (tempCount > count) {
        elements = tempElement;
        //  System.out.println(elements);
        count = tempCount;
      }
    }
  }
  if (count == counter) {
    return elements;
  }
}
if (count < counter) {
  return "";
}
return elements;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
String[] numbers = "756655874075297346".split("");
String elements = "";
int count = 0;
for (String tempElement: numbers) {
  int tempCount = 0;
  for (int n = 0; n < numbers.length; n++) {
    if (numbers[n].equals(tempElement)) {
      tempCount++;
      if (tempCount > count) {
        elements = tempElement;
        //  System.out.println(elements);
        count = tempCount;
      }
    }
  }
}
String x = "";
int c = 2;
do {
  x = findMin(numbers, c++);
} while (x == "");

System.out.println("Frequent number is: " + elements + " It appeared " + count + " times");

System.out.println("Min Frequent number is: " + x + " It appeared " + (c - 1) + " times");
}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- First, you should care about indentation.
- Why slitting the `numbers` string while you can access individual char with `numbers.charAt(n)` ? It force you to work with `String` instead of `char`.
- You don't check for validity of the string. Here, it's hard coded, but if you have to get it from a unknown source, a good habit is to validate it before using.
- Also, you don't check if there's duplicates or not. If `numbers` is "1234567890" your program go for a infinite loop.
- You compute the "Max" count into the `main`, and the "Min" in a function; try to be consistent.
- For both computations, you make \$n*n\$ iterations (where \$n\$ is the `numbers` length) giving a complexity of \$ O(n^2)\$ for both.

Instead, try to construct a table of occurrences by traversing the table once. 
After, simply search in this table the min and max values in one traversal.

There's a very naive implementation, but i think a lot simpler to understand than your, and surely more efficient.

```
public class X {
 public static void main(String[] args) {

   String data = "756655874075297346";
   int[] counts = new int[10];

   for (int i = 0; i < data.length(); i++) {
     char n = data.charAt(i);
     if (n >= '0' && n <= '9') {
        counts[n-'0']++;     
     }
   }

   int min_index = 0;
   int max_index = 0;
   int min_count = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
   int max_count = 0;

   for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
     if (counts[i] >= max_count) {
       max_index = i;
       max_count = counts[i];
     }
     if (counts[i] > 1 && counts[i] < min_count) {
       min_index = i;
       min_count = counts[i];
     }     
   }
  System.out.println("Frequent number is: " + (char)(max_index + '0') + " It appeared " + max_count + " times");
  if (min_count < Integer.MAX_VALUE) {
    System.out.println("Min Frequent number is: " + (char)(min_index + '0') + " It appeared " + min_count + " times");
  }
  else {
    System.out.println("There's no duplicates!");
  }
 }
}
```

Here, the function print the higher number with the higher number of occurrences (in case of multiples char with maximal occurrence count). If instead you want to get the lower, change `if (counts[i] >= max_count)` for `if (counts[i] > max_count)`.

Conversely, it print the lower duplicated number with the lower count, to get the higher duplicated with the lower count, change `counts[i] < min_count` with `counts[i] <= min_count`.